# Flag raised for migration was declined

Tags: discussion, migration, declined-flags

Recently I raised a flag to (for moderator attention) this question ([How to find the Center Coordinate of Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9734821/1671639)) saying,

> This question is about geometry which shall be migrated to
>   math.stackexchange.com

Since math.stackexchange.com is missing in Migration popup, I flagged it under moderator attention

[image]

But it was [**declined**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1671639), saying

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

I thought this question will be suitable for math.stackexchange.com right? Can someone advice on this?

Comment: It is impossible to migration questions more than 60 days old, so even if the mod wanted to migrate it, they couldn't.  The declined message is just a canned message.  The mod probably could have been more specific, but given the volume of flags in the queue, it takes too much time to write custom messages for every decline.

Comment: If you read the comments under the question, it turned out that the OP's problem was a programming error. But even if it wasn't, I'm guessing this question is far too basic for [Mathematics.SE].

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think it'd be too basic, the help page specifically mentions *at any level*.

Comment: @S.L.Barth his underlying problem might have been a typo in his program, but the question itself is a math question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks I was not aware of that *60 days old*.  I was confused because of the comment given by mod and thereby I posted the question here. so can these type of late questions, closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Praveen which is perfectly acceptable.  If you are confused, coming to meta is always a good recourse.  Given the upvotes, a couple of people seem to think it was a good question to ask as well.  I voted to close as a duplicate because the answer is there and now some else who has the same question and finds your question will get sent to the duplicate.